# ADB won't detect my device even after USB Debugging enabled

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

I have a **YUreka AO5510**. It has a custom Cyanogen Lollipop build. Anyway, the problem is I have developer tools enabled, then USB Debugging enabled but whenever I connect my phone to PC, irrespective of, if I have developer tools turned on or not, it gets detected as a Media Device. I checked the settings and it shows three options:

**MTP**
**PTP**
**Charging Only**

By default MTP is turned on. I can switch to others but can't turn off any. One of the options have to be turned on.

Also my device shows up in the Device Manager in the **Portable Devices** category.

How do I get it to be detected in the "Set of online devices" in the Android AVD Manager?

**EDIT 1:** Okay, I just retried PDAnet to the end and it says, "**Please make sure that your device is connected or USB debugging is enabled on it**"

Comment: Have you checked if drivers related to ADB are installed?

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: @AlexP. : Will read it in detail then respond back.

Comment: @tato.rodrigo : Wait a sec...so getting detected as MTP device(which also lets me transfer files) doesn't imply the drivers are installed. Actually, I had also installed PDAnet. It showed, *the drivers for this Device are already installed.* Any specific check?

Comment: @tato.rodrigo : See EDIT 1. This is weird!

Comment: If your device is showing up is irrelevant, this is only the MTP device. The important device is the ADB device. Change the device manager view to "Devices by connection" and see if there is an USB sub-device with missing driver.

Comment: @Robert : No no, this is a tricky problem. I finally figured it out(See my answer)

Answer (score 7):

Yureka! Yureka!

Finally I have been able to figure it out.
All the YUreka users facing this problem, go to `Settings->More->Tethering & Portable Hotspot-> USB Tethering`.<br.

Enable it. You will get a message, USB Debugging enabled and that's it, it will initiate the ADB driver installation on your PC automatically.

Note that you don't have to download any third party tool at all. Just this option will suffice.

Comment: The original Google ADB driver from SDK can also be used after adding two lines to the file `android_winusb.inf`containing `%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, ` and the USB device ID.

Comment: @Robert : That's interesting!. So, you are saying I will find android_winusb.inf driver in the installed SDK directory to do this?(I am a newbie!)

Comment: Yes. You only have to select the "Google USB Driver" in the SDK downloader and afterwards you will find the driver in the subdirectory `extras\google\usb_driver`. However the driver does only recognize a few Android devices but by adding your USB ID to the `[Google.NTamd64]`and/or `[Google.NTx86]`section the driver can be used for your device. I did this for a device the manufacturer does only provide MTP but not ADB driver.

Comment: @Robert : Now that's an advice that would have been useful for my previous chinese phone, with MediaTek chipset, and everything else unheard of. No official driver for that phone and I spent a week setting the drivers up but as my current phone stands, it has a Snapdragon 615 and the phone drivers are available.

Answer (score 1):

After spending an entire morning installing several drivers and reading gobs of articles, the suggestion by Alex P above fixed it.  Fixes for both Linux and my Windows.

I am repeating them here, because the fixes are on a 2014 blog and I am afraid they might disappear.

Linux fix, run on one line, eliminate blank lines:

`find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices -maxdepth 2 -path "*/modalias" -printf "%h\t" -exec cat {} ; | 

awk -F: '/icFFisc42ip0/ {print $1}' | xargs -i cat {}/idVendor | awk '{print"0x"$1}' | sort -u >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

Windows fix, run on one line:

`powershell "gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice | %{wmi} | ?{$.CompatibleID -like "USB\Class_ff^&SubClass_42^&Prot_0?"} | %{write "0x$([regex]::match($.deviceid.tolower(), 'vid_(\w+)').groups[1].value)"} | sort -u" >> %USERPROFILE%.android\adb_usb.ini`